# Why this code (drag ans drop widgets) works in Tkinter but not customtkinter? Any way I could make it work?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

These 2 codes are exactly the same, the only difference is that 1 uses tkinter and the other one uses customtkinter

I am wondering how I could make the customtkinter code work. Is there something that I am missing or something I should change for the second code to work?

In the second code the "drag and drop" functions do not work, while in the first code (tkinter), everything works just fine.
I have included a side note (#this changed) in the second code, to indentify what are the things that changed.

NOTE: the reason I add the comlete code is because all functions shown are needed for the "drag and drop" to work and I do not know where the mistake is.

See below:

With tkinter:

```
import tkinter

def changeOrder(widget1,widget2,initial):

    target=widget1.grid_info()
    widget1.grid(row=initial['row'],column=initial['column'])
    widget2.grid(row=target['row'],column=target['column'])

def on_click(event):

    widget=event.widget
    print(widget)
    if isinstance(widget,tkinter.Label):
        start=(event.x,event.y)
        grid_info=widget.grid_info()
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda event:drag_motion(event,widget,start))
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",lambda event:drag_release(event,widget,grid_info))
    else:
        root.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")

def drag_motion(event,widget,start):


    x = widget.winfo_x()+event.x-start[0]
    y = widget.winfo_y()+event.y-start[1]
    widget.lift()
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)

def drag_release(event,widget,grid_info):


    widget.lower()
    x,y=root.winfo_pointerxy()
    target_widget=root.winfo_containing(x,y)
    if isinstance(target_widget,tkinter.Label): 
        changeOrder(target_widget,widget,grid_info)
    else:
        widget.grid(row=grid_info['row'],column=grid_info['column'])

root = tkinter.Tk()
_entry={}
rows=3
columns = 2
for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        index=(row,column)
        myTextLabel1 = tkinter.Label(root,text="Label 1",bg='yellow')
        myTextLabel1.grid(row=row,column=column,padx=5,pady=5)#sticky=E+W+S+N)
        _entry[index] = myTextLabel1


_entry[index].configure(bg='red')

root.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

With Customtkinter:

```
#WITH CUSTOMTKINTER
import customtkinter

def changeOrder(widget1,widget2,initial):

    target=widget1.grid_info()
    widget1.grid(row=initial['row'],column=initial['column'])
    widget2.grid(row=target['row'],column=target['column'])

def on_click(event):

    widget=event.widget
    print(widget)
    if isinstance(widget,customtkinter.CTkLabel): #this changed
        start=(event.x,event.y)
        grid_info=widget.grid_info()
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda event:drag_motion(event,widget,start))
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",lambda event:drag_release(event,widget,grid_info))
    else:
        root.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")

def drag_motion(event,widget,start):


    x = widget.winfo_x()+event.x-start[0]
    y = widget.winfo_y()+event.y-start[1]
    widget.lift()
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)

def drag_release(event,widget,grid_info):


    widget.lower()
    x,y=root.winfo_pointerxy()
    target_widget=root.winfo_containing(x,y)
    if isinstance(target_widget,customtkinter.CTkLabel): #this changed
        changeOrder(target_widget,widget,grid_info)
    else:
        widget.grid(row=grid_info['row'],column=grid_info['column'])

root = customtkinter.CTk()
_entry={}
rows=3
columns = 2
for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        index=(row,column)
        myTextLabel1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text="Label 1",bg_color='yellow') #this changed
        myTextLabel1.grid(row=row,column=column,padx=5,pady=5)#sticky=E+W+S+N)
        _entry[index] = myTextLabel1


_entry[index].configure(bg_color='red') #this changed

root.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: *What* doesn't work? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Yes i just added that description. Thank you @Julien

Comment: The result of `print(widget)` tells you that the widget triggers the event is not a `customtkinter.CTkLabel`, it is a `tkinter.Label` (created internally by `customtkinter.CTkLabel` class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `customtkinter` widget is basically `tkinter.Frame` which contains other `tkinter` widgets inside it. For example, `customtkinter.CTkLabel` is a `tkinter.Frame` containing a `tkinter.Canvas` and `tkinter.Label`.  So clicking on a *`customtkinter.Label`* will either clicking on the internal `canvas` or `label` based on the position of the mouse cursor actually.

Therefore you need to check the *parent* of the clicked widget instead and move that *parent* instead of the clicked widget:

```py
...

def on_click(event):
    widget = event.widget
    # check widget.master instead
    if isinstance(widget.master, customtkinter.CTkLabel): #this changed
        start = (event.x, event.y)
        # use widget.master instead in below lines
        grid_info = widget.master.grid_info()
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event:drag_motion(event, widget.master, start))
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event:drag_release(event, widget.master, grid_info))
    else:
        root.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")
...

def drag_release(event, widget, grid_info):
    widget.lower()
    x, y = root.winfo_pointerxy()
    target_widget = root.winfo_containing(x, y)
    if target_widget.master != widget and isinstance(target_widget.master, customtkinter.CTkLabel): #this changed
        changeOrder(target_widget.master, widget, grid_info)
    else:
        widget.grid(row=grid_info['row'], column=grid_info['column'])

...
```

Comment: Apprecciate it. It works great!

Comment: Is there a way to drag  2 labels that are on the same row and swap them with another  row of 2 labels at the same time?, instead of doing just 1 label at a time?. I am trying a for-loop but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Group the labels in a row into a frame (like `customtkinter` widget), then move that frame instead. It is better to raise another question on this.

Comment: Yes, I just raised a question If you would like to answer it, very much apprecciated.

Comment: In case youd like the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633096/drag-and-drop-working-when-root-is-bound-but-not-when-frame-in-ctk-is-bound-ho . I also asked about frame binding in the same question.