# Drag and drop working when root is bound, but not when frame in CTk is bound, How could I fix this issue?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, customtkinter

I am able to swap label widgets when dragging and dropping them, they work just fine. However, I can not figure out how to have the same functionality insise a CTk frame.

First, I tried binding the frame (`frame.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)` insetad of `root.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)`), but this does not even move the label widgets. I also did some research I tried the `frame.focus_set()` , but no luck still. Now, I left the "root.bind" and the widgets are able be to dragged, but these just diappeared after these have been dropped. Is there a way I can make the drag and drop functions work with the frame too, and not only the window?.

Additionally, I need help figuring out how to group two widgets and spwaping them with another group of widgets in another row? meaning is a way to drag two label widgets in a row at the same time and drop and swap them with another row of two label widgets. I have tried for-loops in the functions to achieve this, but it doe not seem to be working

Thank you in advance.

NOTE: if the frame widget is commented out  and I place the label widgets (from for-loop) in the window(root) the code works just fine

See code below:

```
import customtkinter

def changeOrder(widget1,widget2,initial):

    target=widget1.grid_info()
    widget1.grid(row=initial['row'],column=initial['column'])
    widget2.grid(row=target['row'],column=target['column'])

def on_click(event):

    widget=event.widget
    print(widget)
    if isinstance(widget.master,customtkinter.CTkLabel):
        start=(event.x,event.y)
        grid_info=widget.master.grid_info()
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda event:drag_motion(event,widget.master,start))
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",lambda event:drag_release(event,widget.master,grid_info))
    else:
        root.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")

def drag_motion(event,widget,start):

    x = widget.winfo_x()+event.x-start[0]
    y = widget.winfo_y()+event.y-start[1]
    widget.lift()
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)

def drag_release(event,widget,grid_info):

    widget.lower()
    x,y=root.winfo_pointerxy()
    target_widget=root.winfo_containing(x,y)
    if isinstance(target_widget.master,customtkinter.CTkLabel): #this changed
        changeOrder(target_widget.master,widget,grid_info)
    else:
        widget.grid(row=grid_info['row'],column=grid_info['column'])

root = customtkinter.CTk()
_entry={}
rows=3
columns = 2
frame=customtkinter.CTkFrame(root, fg_color='lightblue')
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        index=(row,column)
        myTextLabel1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame,text="Label 1",bg_color='yellow')
        myTextLabel1.grid(row=row,column=column,padx=5,pady=5)
        _entry[index] = myTextLabel1

_entry[index].configure(bg_color='blue')

root.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)
# frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is this question different then the other question you asked, which seems identical?

Comment: It works fine when `tkinter.Frame` is used instead of `customtkinter.CTkFrame`.

Comment: Most likely I am not understanding something, but the last question was about how to move customtkinter widgets  when binding. And acw1668 kindly explained that I need to reference the parent instead of the widget inside of it by useing 'master'. Which worked perfectly. But then I tried to use 'master' for the CTkFrane it did not work. Thats why I made this question. on the other hand., I also asked how to swap label widgets from the same row to another row at the same time.  I think acw1668 just anwered question 1 in the comments. Please advise  if need to edit this question. Ty @BryanOakley

Comment: You are right! @acw1668 , However, why I can not add "master" to the CTkFrame like what we did in the pevius question for CTkLabel widgets?. It is not possible?.
How about the grouping of the two label widgets in a row to swap it with another row ? . I am just confused in how you group them after these labels where cretaed with a for loop?

Comment: It is not related to `master`. It *may be* (note that *may be*) something done by `customertkinker` that causes the issue because it works fine when `tkinter.Frame` is used instead of `customtkinter.CTkFrame` for `frame` variable.

Comment: If you don't require to *drag* the two labels together, there is a simple solution to swap the two rows of labels after releasing the *dragged label*.

Comment: I would actually like to drag and drop them together , like what I am able to do with individual label widgets. @acw1668